# WebLogic throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when I compile and deploy a change in my eclipse maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, weblogic

I just started using Maven with eclipse and deployed my application to WebLogic.

When I do a clean install for the first time, my Maven project builds and deploys successfully.

After that, when I make any change to the source code or jsps, I do a pre-clean install to update the project. Now, everytime I do pre-clean install and restart WebLogic I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:283)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:256)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:54)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
```

I did some researches and for some reasons, No one complained about that error before.

Any suggestion what can be the problem ?

This only occurs after I make a change and run "pre-clean install" from within eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I do a clean install for the first time, my maven project builds and deploy successfully.

How is it deployed exactly? Do you use WTP and the Weblogic adapter? Do you use m2eclipse?

> after that, when I make any change to the source code or jsps.. I do a pre-clean install to update the project.

Why do you run `pre-clean`? Do you have anything special bound to `pre-clean` (there is nothing bound to this phase by default). What is the expected result?

> Now, everytime I do pre-clean install and restart weblogic I get the following exception:

What is `FeatureForm`, it it yours? Could this be something you removed that is still referenced by a temporary file generated by WebLogic (e.g. a Servlet generated for a JSP). Does the problem happen with this class only? Did you try to remove the work dir of WebLogic?

> Any suggestion what can be the problem?

I'm not sure I'll be able to answer this question but you need to provide more details about your context and the way you use tools.

Comment: How is it deployed exactly? Do you use WTP and the Weblogic adapter? Do you use m2eclipse? I use M2eclipse to build the project and then in my weblogic Domain, I point the config.xml to the war location.

Comment: Why do you run pre-clean? I run a pre-clean, because I have some static content that gets build on the target directory and if I just did clean it will be removed. I might not even be called the right command. what command should I call to just update the war with the new changes?

Comment: What is FeatureForm, it it yours? Could this be something you removed that is still referenced by a temporary file generated by WebLogic (e.g. a Servlet generated for a JSP). Does the problem happen with this class only? Did you try to remove the work dir of WebLogic? this occured even when I just changed a verbiage from one of the jsps ( just some html text). I dont have any class called FeatureForm. when tracking the stack trace, the exception is within weblogic classes